# How Can I Add a Body Class in Magento Go When the Browser is IE8?

Tags: layout, css, magento-go

I am using the following Custom Layout Update XML in Magento Go to add a body class if the browser is IE8. Currently this code adds the class for every browser instead of only IE8. **How can I write this so it only adds the class for IE8?**

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="addBodyClass">
    <classname>ie8</classname>
    <if>IE 8</if>
  </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: I believe `classname` should be camel case - ie `<className>ie8</className>` . You might also try adding th `<params/>` self closing node before your if, which is how it's normally seen in a layout file ie `<params/><if>lte IE 8</if>`

Comment: @McNab I tried both of those suggestions and neither worked :-(

Comment: Pat, you should add your jQuery code from the chat with Marius as another answer to the question, it'll be useful to someone but possibly not if it's buried in the chat thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit]**

Add the js below in the footer. and it should work.

```
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})");
   //If the regEx through the userAgent is not null
   ieVersion = -1;
   if (re.exec(ua) != null) {
      //Set the IE version
      ieVersion = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
   }
   if (ieVersion == 8){
      $$('body')[0].addClassName('ie8');
   }
}
```

I don't have experience with Magento GO but if it's similar to CE or EE you should have a textarea in the config panel where you can add miscellaneous javascript.

**[OLD answer for Magento CE or EE]**
What you are trying won't work. The `addBodyClass` meyhod acceps only one paramerter... the class name.
What you can do is to create a js file with this content:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('body')[0].addClassName('ie8');
});
```

Let's call this file 'ie8.js' and place it in the js folder.
Now in your layout file add this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
           <type>js</type>
           <name>ie8.js</name>
           <params/><if>IE 8</if>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Clear the cache and give it a go.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. **Could this be because it's Magento Go?** Also, **do you mean clear my browser's cache or is there a cache I have to clear in Magento Go?** The code you said to add to my layout file I instead added to the page's Custom Layout Update XML since Magento Go does not allow editing the `layout.xml`.

Comment: OK. My bad. I skipped the part with Magento Go. I've updated the answer

Comment: Bummer. That didn't work either. The following error is thrown: `'ua' is undefined`

Comment: That's because I'm tired, and forgot one line. I've added it. Try again.

Comment: Dang. Still not working. Magento Go adds "Miscellaneous Scripts" in the head. Should this matter for this script?

Comment: Is `ieVersion = parseInt(RegExp.$1)` supposed to return `NaN` ?

Comment: it worked for me. You can try to use the `Miscellaneous HTML` in the footer section. Just add `<script>` tags around the code.

Comment: That did it! I also came up with my own code that worked and is a little cleaner. Thanks for your help, man!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10636/discussion-between-pat-and-marius)